# Are there any known issues with using custom IAuthorizationPolicy implementation with WCF Service Discovery?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

If I use my custom IAuthorizationPolicy implementation which simply adds additional claims, WCF service discovery will not work, i.e. the DiscoveryClient will not find the services. If I remove the IAuthorizationPolicy implementation, it works fine....are there any known issues or gotchas?